# Memcached Java client with minimum dependencies

Tags: java, memcached

I'd like to use memcached in my java web application, and 
after some digging I found that **spymemcached** and **xmemcached** 
are considered the best ones in java community.
After taking a closer look on these libraries I found that
they use tons of extra libraries (spring, jboss.netty, hibernate, ...)
and it makes sense for me because my java application based on some 3-rd
party application (openfire) which uses jetty as a servlet container
and tends to be simple and fast.

Is there any memcached client implementation that requires not so many dependencies? (Or maybe there is a way to use **spymemcahed** without them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spymemcached only had a lot of dependencies because we added a bunch of stuff to support Membase/Couchbase. For the 2.8 release of Spymemcached though we ripped out all of the Membase/Couchbase stuff out and put it into a new project called Couchbase-Client. In 2.8 the only dependencies are log4j and spring beans. With some easy modifications to the Spymemcached source you could easily remove the spring beans dependency too.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can take a look at [gwhalin](https://github.com/gwhalin/Memcached-Java-Client) memcached java client. It is extremely easy to start using it because it uses no external dependencies.